# How could i add attribute in database with different languages

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller

*/*controller_ problem is that always add the some attribute for the different languages */*

`

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST') && null !== ($request->request->get('ajouter')))` {

        $pack = new Packs();
        $pack->setPackPrice($request->request->get('pack_price'));
        $pack->setDataCreated(new \DateTime('now'));
        $pack->setDataStatus($request->request->get('data_status'));

        foreach ($listLanguages as $language) {
            $packLanguage = new Packs2lng();
            $packLanguage->setLanguage($language);
            $packLanguage->setPack($pack);


            $packLanguage->setPack2lngWording($request->request->get('pack_2lng_wording'));
            $packLanguage->setPack2lngDescription($request->request->get('pack_2lng_description'));

            $em->persist($packLanguage);


        }
```

//view_ I think that my input request must be variable

```
{% for i in listLanguages %}
            <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label col-md-3">Titre </label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="pack_2lng_wording" data-required="1" class="form-control" value="{% if packLanguage.pack2lngWording is defined%}{{packLanguage.pack2lngWording}} {%endif%}"/>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Description </label>
    <textarea cols="60" rows="5" class="span4" name="pack_2lng_description">
        {% if packLanguage.pack2lngDescription is defined%}{{packLanguage.pack2lngDescription}} {%endif%}</textarea>
            </div>
            {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're trying to do. What do you want, what have you tried before and what's exactly your question?

Comment: I'm trying to add that attributes with the differents languages

Comment: And what's you question? And what have you already tried? Why don't you use Symfony Forms?

Comment: I published my views, I'm always looking for solutions without using bundles .

Comment: I think that a solution that i need to make name="pack_2lng_description" in view variable an the some for the controller $request->request->get('pack_2lng_wording') but how ?

Comment: To me, it looks like you want to reinvent the wheel. I'm not sure, but maybe using the right tools will fix your problem. You've only posted a very small part of your code and you didn't asked a question.

Comment: this code work but it add only the last input for the differents languages

Comment: FOR FIRST SOLUTION WITH <input type="text" name="pack_2lng_wording[]" // IT RETURN THIS MESSAGE/ Warning: Illegal offset type     //$packLanguage->setPack2lngWording($request->request->get('pack_2lng_wording')[$language]);

Comment: AND FOR THE SESECOND WITH <input type="text" name="pack_2lng_wording['{{ i }}']/ Object of class //Bundle\Entity\Languages could not be converted to string")

Comment: Any way, Thank you for your help

Comment: What does `$listLanguages` return?

Comment: return list of languages  //$listLanguages = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Languages')->findAll();

Comment: And what does your Language class look like?

Comment: I've updated my answer, based on the assumption that each languages as a `code` attribute (i.e. EN, FR, NL). Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: I tried it: $packLanguage->setPack2lngWording($request->request->get('pack_2lng_wording')[$language->getLanguageAbr()]); // but Notice: Undefined index: Fr

Comment: how i do that with symfony form ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this kind of basic debugging. An important part of programming is debugging, finding out what the problem is. Programming is not dumping your code somewhere and expecting that other people fix your code. One last suggestion: Symfony Form Collections. I seriously can't help you any further.

Comment: Thank you again, I started working with Symfony form, I found it easier and I hope that i does not found problem with data transalation.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?

Comment: Hi Stephan, I have a some difficulty when i deployed my project if u could help me: this my error: Unable to find template "FOSUserBundle:Security:loginMO.html.twig" (looked into: /var/www/vhosts/easy-traffik.com/httpdocs/developer.easy-traffik.com/EasyTraffik/app/Resources/views, /var/www/vhosts/easy-traffik.com/httpdocs/developer.easy-traffik.com/EasyTraffik/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).

Comment: however, it work correctly in localhost but when i deploy my project does not work and other pages of my project working only thatt page of login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the users enters a French and English translation. With your current view, the post request would be this:

- pack_2lng_wording=foo_FR
- pack_2lng_description=bar_FR
- pack_2lng_wording=foo_EN
- pack_2lng_description=bar_EN

That won't work, because the first `pack_2lng_wording` would be overridden by the second.

To prevent it, you have to add `[]` to your `name` attribute of an `input`:

```
<input type="text" name="pack_2lng_wording[]" />
```

Or add `{{ i.code }}` to get a associative array (assuming that each Language has a language code, i.e. a ISO 639-1 code) :

```
<input type="text" name="pack_2lng_wording['{{ i.code }}']" />
```

That would lead to this post request:

- pack_2lng_wording[FR]=foo_FR
- pack_2lng_wording[EN]=foo_EN
- pack_2lng_description[FR]=bar_FR
- pack_2lng_description[EN]=bar_EN

In your controller you have to add `[$language]`:

```
foreach ($listLanguages as $language) {
     $packLanguage = new Packs2lng();
     $packLanguage->setLanguage($language);
     $packLanguage->setPack($pack);

     $packLanguage->setPack2lngWording($request->request->get('pack_2lng_wording')[$language->getCode()]);
     $packLanguage->setPack2lngDescription($request->request->get('pack_2lng_description')[$language->getCode()]);
}
```

BTW: I would highly recommend to use Symfony Forms. You are now reinventing the wheel. That's OK if you want to learn, but it will make your life easier (and your application) better if you are using components that are well documented, well maintained, etc.